# Is there a way to deploy an Azure DevOps repo to an Azure VM?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Essentially what I'm wanting to happen is the following:

1. Push changes to .NET Core app in Azure DevOps repo
2. Changes get pulled down to an Azure VM
3. dotnet publish the pulled down code to a directory

I've tried creating a Release pipeline and I'm able to create an IIS website, etc. but there aren't any options for deploying a .NET Core app

Comment: If you install a DevOps agent on the VM. It can (apparently) run deploys local to the VM. Here are a few links. https://sameeraman.wordpress.com/2018/12/10/local-self-hosted-agents-in-azure-devops/ https://devopsjournal.io/blog/2020/03/29/Deploy-locally-on-Windows-Azure-DevOps

Answer (score 0):

The Azure DevOps Project simplifies the setup of an entire continuous integration (CI) and continuous delivery (CD) pipeline to Azure with Azure DevOps. You can start with existing code or use one of the provided sample applications. Then you can quickly deploy that application to various Azure services such as Virtual Machines, App Service, Azure Kubernetes Services (AKS), Azure SQL Database, and Azure Service Fabric.
it is explained in the below link.
https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/azuredevopsprojectdotnet/